# Frame into a large 1D array

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

I'm sending a single grayscale frame (160x120) from LabVIEW to this C-program through TCP. I managed to convert the bytes to uint32 pixel values. The goal here is that I will define every 19203  bytes as an image array where the first byte is a header which defines the ID of the array, the second and third bytes defines the resolution (120 and 160) and the last 19200 bytes are the received bytes from the LabVIEW program. The purpose is that the first byte of the first array will get the value "1", and the first byte of the second array will get the value "2" and so on.

The problem in this case occurs when I examine the 19203 bytes. I can clearly see that every uint32 value seems correct until value 4801. From that value and up to 19203, I get a constant weird value: "3435973836", that has nothing to do with the grayscale pixels, since it can only between 0 and 300. Where does the error occur ?.

[image: Result]

```
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 19203

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s , new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    int c;
    int iResult;
    int receivedCount = 0;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    typedef unsigned int uint8_t;
    unsigned long totalReceived = 0, totalExpected=160*120;
    unsigned int i;
    uint32_t image[DEFAULT_BUFLEN]; 
    size_t len;
    uint8_t* p;
    uint8_t value;
    int x=0;
    int z=0;

    p = (uint8_t*)recvbuf;

    do
    {
        iResult = recv( new_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        for(z=1; z<11; z++)
        {
            image[0] = z;

            for(i=0, x=1; i<19202,x<19203; i++, x++)
            {
                image [x] = p[i];
                printf("%lu\n",image[x]);
            }
        }   
    }
    while(iResult > 0 );

    closesocket(new_socket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`recv()` may not necessarily read all of the bytes you ask it to -- it's likely returning fewer bytes than you asked for.  You need to always check the return value of `recv()` and only process that many bytes.  By ignoring the return value, you're reading uninitialized memory.

The number 3435973836 is much more elucidating in hexadecimal -- it's 0xcccccccc.  This [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_debug_values) is used by the Visual Studio runtime to initialize stack memory in Debug builds, so when you see that value, you know you're reading uninitialized stack memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam. Do you have any coding suggestion to handle the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the DEFAULT_BUFLEN size as I can't see it declared in your code. Maybe that's causing a buffer overflow, as array image[] is using it as argument when declared.

Comment: Sorry. I just didn't add it before

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer is `19203` *bytes* long, but you are iterating it with *uint32*, so 4 bytes at a time:

```
uint32_t image[DEFAULT_BUFLEN]; 
[...]
for(i=0, x=1; i<19202,x<19203; i++, x++)
{
    image [x] = [...];

// sizeof(uint32) == 4
```

So when attempting to read the `uint32` at index `4801` you read outside of your buffer:

```
sizeof(uint32) * 4801 == 19204
using image[4801] is undefined behaviour, even image[4800] is ub
```

Another thing to consider is the condition `i<19202,x<19203` in your loop should be replaced with `i<19202 && x<19203`, the former uses the comma operator, which is not the same as logical conjunction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I have to declare both lines in the top of the code ?

Comment: @user2292615 you should not attempt to read `image[4800]` or any later index when `image` is an array of `uint32`.

Comment: That uint32 value was actually a mistake. It should be uint_8 instead. But it doesn't change anything ?

Comment: @user2292615 this line is relevant: `uint32_t image[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];` -- for the sake of an example, let's say you do `image[1] = 0` -- do you know which bytes of the buffer will be zeroed?

Comment: I actually increased the size of DEFAULT_BUFLEN by factor 4, so it seems like everything works now. According to your question, the answer is "no".